Cannot create a new safe account using safe-infrastructure
Our Eclipse Testnet info was already included on Safe-singleton-factory, Safe-deployments, Safe-core-sdk, and Safe-wallet-web repositories.
Based on that, I have been trying to execute safe-infrastructure repo on my local end.
I was following up on the guide doc to run it locally and could add my chain info on http://localhost:8000/cfg/admin/.
Here's my chainInfo:
 {
  "count": 1,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "chainId": "555666",
      "chainName": "EclipseChain Testnet",
      "shortName": "EclipseChain Testnet",
      "description": "",
      "chainLogoUri": "http://localhost:8000/cfg/media/chains/555666/chain_logo_16hZikh.png",
      "l2": true,
      "isTestnet": true,
      "rpcUri": {
        "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
        "value": "https://subnets.avax.network/eclipsecha/testnet/rpc"
      },
      "safeAppsRpcUri": {
        "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
        "value": "https://subnets.avax.network/eclipsecha/testnet/rpc"
      },
      "publicRpcUri": {
        "authentication": "NO_AUTHENTICATION",
        "value": "https://subnets.avax.network/eclipsecha/testnet/rpc"
      },
      "blockExplorerUriTemplate": {
        "address": "https://subnets-test.avax.network/eclipsecha/address/{{address}}",
        "txHash": "https://subnets-test.avax.network/eclipsecha/tx/{{txHash}}",
        "api": "https://subnets-test.avax.network/eclipsecha/api?module={{module}}&action={{action}}&address={{address}}&apiKey={{apiKey}}"
      },
      "nativeCurrency": {
        "name": "EclipseChain Token",
        "symbol": "ECLPS",
        "decimals": 18,
        "logoUri": "http://localhost:8000/cfg/media/chains/555666/currency_logo_3No25Fo.png"
      },
      "pricesProvider": {
        "nativeCoin": null,
        "chainName": null
      },
      "transactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
      "vpcTransactionService": "http://nginx:8000/txs",
      "theme": {
        "textColor": "#ffffff",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      },
      "gasPrice": [],
      "ensRegistryAddress": null,
      "recommendedMasterCopyVersion": "1.3.0",
      "disabledWallets": [],
      "features": [
        "CONTRACT_INTERACTION",
        "DOMAIN_LOOKUP",
        "ERC1155",
        "ERC721",
        "SAFE_APPS",
        "SPENDING_LIMIT"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The problem is that it loads forever in the indexing step when I create a new safe account.
I confirmed that a new safe account has been created and validated on our Eclipse Testnet.
https://subnets-test.avax.network/eclipsecha/address/0x5B98302A87384999Be83eC3232aa213521d5DAF1
https://subnets-test.avax.network/eclipsecha/tx/0xec633f520f18e6bd16fa3b53bf4b9f53937e8ae7f676aa5bc9a0a3dff47bc5cb
I attached some screenshot images so you can see what's the issue on my side.

Frontend UI:


Docker logs of safe-infrastructure-cgw-web-1:


Docker logs of safe-infrastructure-txs-worker-index-1:


Response of Endpoint http://localhost:8000/txs/api/v1/about/indexing/
{"currentBlockNumber":10753,"erc20BlockNumber":0,"erc20Synced":false,"masterCopiesBlockNumber":10753,"masterCopiesSynced":true,"synced":false}


Please let me know what is the root cause and how to fix it.
Thank you.

Thanks for reaching out. Could you please add the logs from worker-indexer, and also what is the indexing endpoint response in the tx service  txs/api/v1/about/indexing/. Thank you in advance

@Louis-SafeCoreTeam Thank you for your prompt response, I added more info(logs of worker-index and response of endpoint) you need in the above question. Please let me know if you need more information.

@Louis-SafeCoreTeam Hello how are you, do you have an update for me? thanks.

Hi, backend lead for Safe here, are you using the L2 version of the Safe contract when deploying new Safes?

@Uxío Hello, I already deployed both safe-deployments v1.3.0 and v1.4.1 contracts.
Also, I set L2 version as true when setting my chaininfo. (you can check my chainInfo in the above)
How do I confirm if I use L2 version of the Safe contract or not?

I finally solved it...
There are 2 problems that I missed.

Use the correct shortName, I didn't follow Eip-3779 name.(in my case, shortName is eclipset)
Add master copies(safe_l2 and safe contract) and proxy factory contract addresses from safe-deployments repo, by interacting  http://localhost:8000/txs/admin/.

The following post is helpful for me.
Problem with running safe transaction service locally

As @happyleow said, the EIP-3779 short names are imported direct into the Config service from Chainlist at https://chainid.network/shortNameMapping.json.
Picking the right short name fixed the problem for me too.
